# what is wrong with this code - get taxonomy from theme option

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I need to query posts from custom post taxonomy (set by user from WordPress theme option panel).

I am using the following code:

```
<?php

 if ( function_exists( 'get_option_tree') ) {
     $taxonomy = get_option_tree( 'taxonomy_option' );
 }

 $args = array(
    'project_type' => $taxonomy,
    'show_count'   => 6,
    );

 query_posts($args); 

?>
```

The code is working just if I enter on `'project_type' => 'my taxonomy name'`. What is wrong with the code above? How I can get an option (option-tree) into args array? Later edit: the optiontree function render the taxonomy ID.

thanks

Comment: Where are you adding those code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_option_tree()` might be giving you an array, you should check it out with

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($taxonomy,true)."</pre>";
```

**Update:**

After some discussion with @Ad Reactor, we found out that the `$taxonomy` output was a number instead of a slug. To get the slug, we can use

```
$term = get_term( 1234, 'project_type' ); 
$slug= $term->slug;
```

where `1234` is replaced with the real `term_id`

Comment: by taxonomy ID you mean the taxonomy term slug? I mean you get a string value instead of some number?

Comment: no, i mean a taxonomy ID (number). in same way like at a category ID.

Comment: but I think you need a slug instead of a number. Your working example is with a slug but not a number.

Comment: probably you have rite. but i try to get the slug from the option and still not working: $term = get_term( $id, $taxonomy ); $slug = $term->slug; on array goes  'project_type' => $slug,

Comment: so do you get the slug if you use `$term = get_term( 1234, 'project_type' ); `where you replace 1234 with some real term_id?

Comment: you should also check out `print_r(get_option_tree());` just to see all the values available, not just for the 'taxonomy_option'.

Comment: was my fault, i put the option on taxonomy instead on id in the get_term. thank you very much for help. if you edit your answer i will mark like accepted. kind regards

Comment: ps: there is also a way to use the `term_id`, if you use the `tax_query` parameter, see more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see is `$taxonomy` is not initialised and because of that if your condition does not met the `$taxonomy` will be undefined.

So define `$taxonomy` above your `if` condition.

```
$taxonomy = '';
if ( function_exists( 'get_option_tree') ) {
.....
```

Comment: even i enter $taxonomy = get_option_tree( 'taxonomy_option' ); without condition (it work for post categories), on custom post type isn't working. regards